# Abstract Factory pattern with 2 factory methods

Tags: java, spring, factory-pattern

In a spring hibernate java project with(controller - services - dao - entity layers), i am having abstract factory pattern (the abstract class has 2 abstract methods). In the implemented classes of abstract factory pattern i am having dao methods(to run the named queries). Now when the request comes to the service impl the dao from another Service class it gives null pointer excecption
I have autowired the dao classes in the services impl
`

```
AbstractFruitService - [addToBasket() and removeFromBasket()] 
|
|- SeasonalFruitsServicsImpl - SeasonalFruitsDAO
| 
|- BerryFruitsServiceImpl - BerryFruitsDAO
```

i cant add @Service("abstractFruitService") to both SeasonalFruitsServicsImpl and BerryFruitsServiceImpl it gives error - conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class

Not sure if the spring static/instance factory method is useful in this case, i tries this also but didnt work

Is there any approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the annotation `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` works perfect for my code, on the service method i add this functionality and it worked fine

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing rather looks like a Service Locator pattern, Service Locator is an *alternative* to Dependency Injection. So there's no reason to implement one if you are already using IoC Spring Container.

Can declare your `SeasonalFruitsServiceImpl` and `BerryFruitsServiceImpl` as separate beans, and request their instances from the container either using their respective interfaces  `SeasonalFruitsDAO` and `BerryFruitsDAO`, or by providing them with the separate names(if you need to replace the implementations then you just register another implementations in the container).

See [Martin J. Fowler article](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html)

If the service locator was provided by some 3rd party then you should create an instance of Service Locator

```
<bean id="someServiceLocator" class="com.some3rdparty.ServiceLocator"/>
<bean id="seasonalFruitsDao" factory-bean="someServiceLocator" factory-method="createSeasonalFruitDao"/>
<bean id="berryFruitsDao" factory-bean="someServiceLocator" factory-method="createBerryFruitsDao"/>
```

or with java code configuration

```
@Configuration
public class someServiceLocatorConfiguration{
  @Bean
  public ServiceLocator locator(){
    return new com.some3rdparty.ServiceLocator();
  }
  @Bean()
  public SeasonalFruitsDao  seasonalFruitsDao(){
    return locator().createSeasonalFruitDao();
  }
  @Bean()
  public SeasonalFruitsDao  seasonalFruitsDao(){
    return locator().createSeasonalFruitDao();
  }
}
```

but of course you should never ever do it to instantiate objects developed by you.